Extrude function not working right
I am doing the blender guru donut tutorial for 4.0 and when I extrude to pull up the plates it looks fine but when I change the angle I'm looking at the object a realize it is completely messed up. Can someone please help I can't progress in the tutorial without fixing this.

You have Snapping enabled (Face project). It is in the upper menu and uses a magnet icon.
Click it to toggle snapping.
It has a Shift+Tab shorcut and uses Ctrl+Shift+Tab for options

Thank you so much it worked.
